# Autoincrementing conversion - What am I missing here?

Tags: php, mongodb

please refer to the following location
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

In the specified URL (above) there is a sample code for auto increment logic in  java script which was converted to php (I have provided the code below) - I am not able to make it error free. could any one correct me  where I have gone wrong in the conversion?

```
<?php
function getNextSequence($name) {
global $db;
   $ret = $db->counters->findAndModify(
          array(
            'query'=>array( '_id'=>name),
            'update'=>array( '$inc'=> 

array('seq'=> 1) ),
            'new'=>'true'
          )
   );
   return $ret->seq;
}

$db = new MongoClient();
$db = $db->test;

$db->counters->insert(
array(
    '_id'=>"userid",
     'seq'=>0
      )
);
$db->users->insert(
   array(
     '_id'=> getNextSequence("userid"),
     'name'=> "Sarah C."
   )
);

$db->users->insert(
   array(
     '_id'=> getNextSequence("userid"),
     'name'=> "Bob D."
   )
);
$ret = $db->users->find();
print_r($ret);
?>
```

PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name' in C:\php\seq.php on line 6
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoResultException' with message 'need remove or update' in C:\php\seq.php:10
Stack trace:
    #0 C:\php\seq.php(10): MongoCollection->findAndModify(Array)
    #1 C:\php\seq.php(25): getNextSequence('userid')
    #2 {main}
    thrown in C:\php\seq.php on line 10

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `$` for the `$name` variable.
Also, the arguments you are passing to the findAndModify helper are inccrect,see https://www.php.net/mongocollection.findandmodify for more info.

The correct getNextSequence() for your script should be:

```
<?php
function getNextSequence($name) {
    global $db;

    $ret = $db->counters->findAndModify(
        array( '_id' => $name),
        array('$inc' => array('seq' => 1)),
        array(),
        array('new' => true)
    );
    return $ret["seq"];
}
```